# "Fine grain Cross-VM Attacks on Xen and VMware are possible" and OpenSSL 0.9.7

Tags: aes, openssl, timing-attack

Here's a paper that just made its way into Cryptology ePrint Archive: [Fine grain Cross-VM Attacks on Xen and VMware are possible!](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/248).

Its a good survey of past attacks and presents a couple of new techniques for AES against OpenSSL, PolarSSL and Libgcrypt.

Why did the authors use OpenSSL 0.9.7? That's from 2007, and I don't believe its even supported any longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the authors used *both* OpenSSL 0.9.7 and 1.0.1; they detail the differences between the versions, what changed in the implementations, and what they can do from other VM.

They refer to 0.9.7 because that was the version used by Bernstein in 2003 when he worked on cache-timing attacks on AES. This allows to highlight how much (or how little) the cross-VM boundary complicates things for the attacker. They also did tests on 1.0.1, since that's the current, modern version.